# How to center Framelayout horizontally and vertically in Mobile screen

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm using Framelayout inside Linearlayout.Frmelayout contains two imageview. I am looking to center whole framelayout in center. I can align child inside Framlyout with attribute gravity:center. 
But problem is when I use this then both imageview aligns at center but I want second image to appear at the boarder of first image which is camera icon such that user would know that they can edit pic if they click the imageicon.

Here is my Framelayout

```html
 
 <Linearlayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            
            
 
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/userimage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/regUserPhoto"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/drawable_male"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                app:border="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
                app:border_width="4dp"
                app:shadow="true" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_camera"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/camera_button" />


        </FrameLayout>
        
        </Linearlayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it super fast using [CostraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout), you can do it with `Linearlayout` but it will cause your layout to become a very nested layout (could affect your performance in more complicated layous).

**Here is an example for your wanted layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layoutDirection="ltr"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/play_button"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/play_button"
    android:text="PIC"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/play_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/rose" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Your layout will look like this:**

[image]

If you want to change your image size just change those attributes values:

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent
```